# не могу сделать переадресацию по значению из инпута

Tags: javascript, php

В общем есть им магазин, и хочу чтобы при оформлении заказа сразу кидала на страницу что все успешно и сразу редирект на страницу оплаты, решил сделать так

```
<a href="<?=$params['payment_link']?>" class="com-rbs2__submit _credit-type-<?=$params['CREDIT_TYPE'];?>">asdasd</a>
     <input id="reurl"type="hidden" name="name" value="<?=$params['payment_link']?>">

            <script>
                        var text = $('#reurl').val();
                                                window.location.assign('text');
                                            </script>
```

но в итоге перекидывает по ссылке site.ru/text что я делаю не так? помогите пожалуйтса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var text = $('#reurl').val();
window.location.assign(text); // not 'text'
```

Comment: ох как же не доглядел))) спать пора, спасибо вам